# try using mode split test from semantic segmentation but it get erro

Tags: python, semantic-segmentation

So, I'm trying semantic segmentation using ade20k dataset and have already made some code with base from gluon-cv [here](https://cv.gluon.ai/_modules/gluoncv/data/ade20k/segmentation.html) and from github [here](https://github.com/zhanghang1989/PyTorch-Encoding/blob/master/encoding/datasets/ade20k.py). It actually work when I set split mode to train and val. but for test it get failure all the time

here is my full code :

```
import os
import random
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.utils.data as data

from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageFilter

class ADE20KSegmentation(data.Dataset):
    BASE_DIR = 'ADEChallengeData2016'
    NUM_CLASS = 150
    CLASSES = ("wall", "building, edifice", "sky", "floor, flooring", "tree",
               "ceiling", "road, route", "bed", "windowpane, window", "grass",
               "cabinet", "sidewalk, pavement",
               "person, individual, someone, somebody, mortal, soul",
               "earth, ground", "door, double door", "table", "mountain, mount",
               "plant, flora, plant life", "curtain, drape, drapery, mantle, pall",
               "chair", "car, auto, automobile, machine, motorcar",
               "water", "painting, picture", "sofa, couch, lounge", "shelf",
               "house", "sea", "mirror", "rug, carpet, carpeting", "field", "armchair",
               "seat", "fence, fencing", "desk", "rock, stone", "wardrobe, closet, press",
               "lamp", "bathtub, bathing tub, bath, tub", "railing, rail", "cushion",
               "base, pedestal, stand", "box", "column, pillar", "signboard, sign",
               "chest of drawers, chest, bureau, dresser", "counter", "sand", "sink",
               "skyscraper", "fireplace, hearth, open fireplace", "refrigerator, icebox",
               "grandstand, covered stand", "path", "stairs, steps", "runway",
               "case, display case, showcase, vitrine",
               "pool table, billiard table, snooker table", "pillow",
               "screen door, screen", "stairway, staircase", "river", "bridge, span",
               "bookcase", "blind, screen", "coffee table, cocktail table",
               "toilet, can, commode, crapper, pot, potty, stool, throne",
               "flower", "book", "hill", "bench", "countertop",
               "stove, kitchen stove, range, kitchen range, cooking stove",
               "palm, palm tree", "kitchen island",
               "computer, computing machine, computing device, data processor, "
               "electronic computer, information processing system",
               "swivel chair", "boat", "bar", "arcade machine",
               "hovel, hut, hutch, shack, shanty",
               "bus, autobus, coach, charabanc, double-decker, jitney, motorbus, "
               "motorcoach, omnibus, passenger vehicle",
               "towel", "light, light source", "truck, motortruck", "tower",
               "chandelier, pendant, pendent", "awning, sunshade, sunblind",
               "streetlight, street lamp", "booth, cubicle, stall, kiosk",
               "television receiver, television, television set, tv, tv set, idiot "
               "box, boob tube, telly, goggle box",
               "airplane, aeroplane, plane", "dirt track",
               "apparel, wearing apparel, dress, clothes",
               "pole", "land, ground, soil",
               "bannister, banister, balustrade, balusters, handrail",
               "escalator, moving staircase, moving stairway",
               "ottoman, pouf, pouffe, puff, hassock",
               "bottle", "buffet, counter, sideboard",
               "poster, posting, placard, notice, bill, card",
               "stage", "van", "ship", "fountain",
               "conveyer belt, conveyor belt, conveyer, conveyor, transporter",
               "canopy", "washer, automatic washer, washing machine",
               "plaything, toy", "swimming pool, swimming bath, natatorium",
               "stool", "barrel, cask", "basket, handbasket", "waterfall, falls",
               "tent, collapsible shelter", "bag", "minibike, motorbike", "cradle",
               "oven", "ball", "food, solid food", "step, stair", "tank, storage tank",
               "trade name, brand name, brand, marque", "microwave, microwave oven",
               "pot, flowerpot", "animal, animate being, beast, brute, creature, fauna",
               "bicycle, bike, wheel, cycle", "lake",
               "dishwasher, dish washer, dishwashing machine",
               "screen, silver screen, projection screen",
               "blanket, cover", "sculpture", "hood, exhaust hood", "sconce", "vase",
               "traffic light, traffic signal, stoplight", "tray",
               "ashcan, trash can, garbage can, wastebin, ash bin, ash-bin, ashbin, "
               "dustbin, trash barrel, trash bin",
               "fan", "pier, wharf, wharfage, dock", "crt screen",
               "plate", "monitor, monitoring device", "bulletin board, notice board",
               "shower", "radiator", "glass, drinking glass", "clock", "flag")
    def __init__(self, root, split='train',
                base_size=256, crop_size=224, mode=None, transform=None, target_transform=None, **kwargs):
        super(ADE20KSegmentation, self).__init__()
        # assert exists and prepare dataset automatically
        root = os.path.join(root, self.BASE_DIR)
        self.mode = mode if mode is not None else split
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform
        self.base_size = base_size
        self.crop_size = crop_size
        assert os.path.exists(root), "Please setup the dataset using" + \
            "encoding/scripts/prepare_ade20k.py"
        self.images, self.masks = _get_ade20k_pairs(root, split)
        if split != 'test':
            assert (len(self.images) == len(self.masks))
        if len(self.images) == 0:
            raise(RuntimeError("Found 0 images in subfolders of: \
                " + root + "\n"))


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = PIL.Image.open(self.images[index]).convert('RGB')
        if self.mode == 'test':
            if self.transform is not None:
                img = self.transform(img)
            return img, os.path.basename(self.images[index])
        mask = PIL.Image.open(self.masks[index])
        # synchrosized transform
        if self.mode == 'train':
            img, mask = self._sync_transform(img, mask)
        elif self.mode == 'val':
            img, mask = self._val_sync_transform(img, mask)
        else:
            assert self.mode == 'testval'
            mask = self._mask_transform(mask)
        # general resize, normalize and toTensor
        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)
        if self.target_transform is not None:
            mask = self.target_transform(mask)
        return img, mask

    def _val_sync_transform(self, img, mask):
        outsize = self.crop_size
        short_size = outsize
        w, h = img.size
        if w > h:
            oh = short_size
            ow = int(1.0 * w * oh / h)
        else:
            ow = short_size
            oh = int(1.0 * h * ow / w)
        img = img.resize((ow, oh), PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
        mask = mask.resize((ow, oh), PIL.Image.NEAREST)
        # center crop
        w, h = img.size
        x1 = int(round((w - outsize) / 2.))
        y1 = int(round((h - outsize) / 2.))
        img = img.crop((x1, y1, x1 + outsize, y1 + outsize))
        mask = mask.crop((x1, y1, x1 + outsize, y1 + outsize))
        # final transform
        img, mask = self._img_transform(img), self._mask_transform(mask)
        return img, mask

    def _sync_transform(self, img, mask):
       # random mirror
       if random.random() < 0.5:
           img = img.transpose(PIL.Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
           mask = mask.transpose(PIL.Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
       crop_size = self.crop_size
       # random scale (short edge)
       w, h = img.size
       long_size = random.randint(int(self.base_size*0.5), int(self.base_size*2.0))
       if h > w:
           oh = long_size
           ow = int(1.0 * w * long_size / h + 0.5)
           short_size = ow
       else:
           ow = long_size
           oh = int(1.0 * h * long_size / w + 0.5)
           short_size = oh
       img = img.resize((ow, oh), PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
       mask = mask.resize((ow, oh), PIL.Image.NEAREST)
       # pad crop
       if short_size < crop_size:
           padh = crop_size - oh if oh < crop_size else 0
           padw = crop_size - ow if ow < crop_size else 0
           img = ImageOps.expand(img, border=(0, 0, padw, padh), fill=0)
           mask = ImageOps.expand(mask, border=(0, 0, padw, padh), fill=0)
       # random crop crop_size
       w, h = img.size
       x1 = random.randint(0, w - crop_size)
       y1 = random.randint(0, h - crop_size)
       img = img.crop((x1, y1, x1+crop_size, y1+crop_size))
       mask = mask.crop((x1, y1, x1+crop_size, y1+crop_size))
       # gaussian blur as in PSP
       if random.random() < 0.5:
           img = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(
               radius=random.random()))
       # final transform
       return img, self._mask_transform(mask)

    def _img_transform(self, img):
        return np.array(img)

    def _mask_transform(self, mask):
        return torch.from_numpy(np.array(mask)).long()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)

    @property
    def classes(self):
        """Category names."""
        return type(self).CLASSES

    @property
    def pred_offset(self):
        return 1


def _get_ade20k_pairs(folder, split='train'):
    def get_path_pairs(img_folder, mask_folder):
        img_paths = []
        mask_paths = []
        for filename in os.listdir(img_folder):
            basename, _ = os.path.splitext(filename)
            if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
                imgpath = os.path.join(img_folder, filename)
                maskname = basename + '.png'
                maskpath = os.path.join(mask_folder, maskname)
                if os.path.isfile(maskpath):
                    img_paths.append(imgpath)
                    mask_paths.append(maskpath)
                else:
                    print('cannot find the mask:', maskpath)
        return img_paths, mask_paths

    if split == 'train':
        img_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'images/training')
        mask_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'annotations/training')
        img_paths, mask_paths = get_path_pairs(img_folder, mask_folder)
        print('len(img_paths):', len(img_paths))
        assert len(img_paths) == 20210
    elif split == 'val':
        img_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'images/validation')
        mask_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'annotations/validation')
        img_paths, mask_paths = get_path_pairs(img_folder, mask_folder)
        print('len(img_paths):', len(img_paths))
        assert len(img_paths) == 2000
    else:
        assert split == 'trainval'
        train_img_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'images/training')
        train_mask_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'annotations/training')
        val_img_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'images/validation')
        val_mask_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'annotations/validation')
        train_img_paths, train_mask_paths = get_path_pairs(train_img_folder, train_mask_folder)
        val_img_paths, val_mask_paths = get_path_pairs(val_img_folder, val_mask_folder)
        img_paths = train_img_paths + val_img_paths
        mask_paths = train_mask_paths + val_mask_paths
        assert len(img_paths) == 22210
    return img_paths, mask_paths

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataset = ADE20KSegmentation(root='/content/dataset', split='test')
    img, label = dataset[0]
```

and this is the error

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-75127ee3fbef> in <module>()
    228 
    229 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 230     dataset = ADE20KSegmentation(root='/content/dataset', split='test')
    231     img, label = dataset[0]

1 frames
<ipython-input-6-75127ee3fbef> in __init__(self, root, split, base_size, crop_size, mode, transform, target_transform, **kwargs)
     82         self.crop_size = crop_size
     83         assert os.path.exists(root), "Please setup the dataset using" +             "encoding/scripts/prepare_ade20k.py"
---> 84         self.images, self.masks = _get_ade20k_pairs(root, split)
     85         if split != 'test':
     86             assert (len(self.images) == len(self.masks))

<ipython-input-6-75127ee3fbef> in _get_ade20k_pairs(folder, split)
    215         assert len(img_paths) == 2000
    216     else:
--> 217         assert split == 'trainval'
    218         train_img_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'images/training')
    219         train_mask_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'annotations/training')

AssertionError:
```

and I think the main error is on the _mask_transform function. I but it makes me confuse because it works well for train and val but fail in test. I have already change al split mode on definition to test but still can't works well

Answer (score 1):

There is no code written for test split.

```
 if split == 'train':
        img_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'images/training')
        mask_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'annotations/training')
        img_paths, mask_paths = get_path_pairs(img_folder, mask_folder)
        print('len(img_paths):', len(img_paths))
        assert len(img_paths) == 20210
    elif split == 'val':
        img_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'images/validation')
        mask_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'annotations/validation')
        img_paths, mask_paths = get_path_pairs(img_folder, mask_folder)
        print('len(img_paths):', len(img_paths))
        assert len(img_paths) == 2000
    else:
        assert split == 'trainval'
        train_img_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'images/training')
        train_mask_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'annotations/training')
        val_img_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'images/validation')
        val_mask_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'annotations/validation')
        train_img_paths, train_mask_paths = get_path_pairs(train_img_folder, train_mask_folder)
        val_img_paths, val_mask_paths = get_path_pairs(val_img_folder, val_mask_folder)
        img_paths = train_img_paths + val_img_paths
        mask_paths = train_mask_paths + val_mask_paths
        assert len(img_paths) == 22210
    return img_paths, mask_paths
```

Check this set mode to `None`
by

```
dataset = ADE20KSegmentation(root='/content/dataset', split='test',mode='test')
    img, label = dataset[0]
```